# How to resolve my website url within a service-worker?

Tags: service-worker

I am receiving web push notifications.

They have a `type` field added by me.

Based on the type I want to open different urls in my website.

I tried `self.location` and it points to the service worker fine enough. But sometimes I host sw in another place domain than the website.

My onnotificationclick handler code is as

```
targetClient = await self.clients.openWindow('');
```

This is opening the source code of the service worker...

I also can't access window object within service worker to resolve the url.

Any suggestion?

If I am out of ideas I can inject a variable hardcode my site url inside the sw as well but that is uglier and not environment specific solution.